# Angular testing techniques Jasmine vs karma vs protractor in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

I am new in angular testing. Can anyone tell me about the difference between these above 3 techniques?

Answer (score 48):

[**Jasmine**](https://jasmine.github.io/) is a behavior-driven development **framework for testing** JavaScript code. It does not depend on any other JavaScript frameworks. It does not require a DOM. And it has a clean, obvious syntax so that you can easily write tests.

[**Karma**](http://karma-runner.github.io) is essentially a **tool** for testing which **spawns a web server** that executes source code against test code for each of the browsers connected. The results of each test against each browser are examined and displayed via the command line to the developer such that they can see which browsers and tests passed or failed.

Jasmine and Karma are usually used together to perform Unit testing or integration testing.

[**Protractor**](http://www.protractortest.org) is an **end-to-end test framework** for Angular and AngularJS applications. Protractor runs tests against your application running in a real browser, interacting with it as a user would without depending on other tools for performing the same. [Check out how it works here](https://www.protractortest.org/#/infrastructure).

**References:**

[Jasmine Documentation](https://jasmine.github.io/)

[Karma - How it works?](http://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/intro/how-it-works.html)

[Protractor](http://www.protractortest.org)

Comment: this doesn't says much about how does everything fits together in an angular app...

Comment: It was not required as per the question.

Answer (score 10):

Karma is test runner like grunt and gulp
Jasmine is a BDD framework for testing

You can write expectations i.e. tests in jasmine and run it using Karma.

Protractor does this both the things for you.

Answer (score 8):

Protractor is a Selenium wrapper, it's not a testing framework itself. Protractor includes Jasmine, see conf.js on [official page](http://www.protractortest.org/#/tutorial)

```
exports.config = {
  framework: 'jasmine',
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['spec.js']
}
```